# Turning off logging in Paramiko

Tags: python, logging, paramiko

I am using the ssh client provided by Paramiko to create a function call `remoteSSH` (the file name is `remoteConnect.py`):

```
import paramiko
import logging
logger = paramiko.util.logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)

def remoteSSH(username,userpasswd):
    ....
```

Now I am calling the `remoteSSH` function in another Python module called `getData()` (`getdata.py`):

```
from remoteConnect import *
import logging
logger2=logging.getLogger()
logger2.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

However,  a call to `logger2.info('ccc')` also turns on all INFO level logging in the file that is importing the Paramiko module (i.e. `remoteConnect.py`)

How do I turn off logging in `remoteConnect.py` so that Paramiko does not spit out all the INFO level messages?

Comment: Use `WARNING` - `WARN` is deprecated.

Answer (score 79):

Paramiko names its logggers. It seems to function as the logging modules in other languages (JDK logging comes to mind) do.

I've found that

`logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` helps.

(You can put this inside the module that's importing paramiko - just make sure the 'logging' module is enabled as well).

It took me a while to figure out how to do this (in fact, it wasn't until I actually started dealing with Java logging that this answer came to mind)

Comment: `pysftp` module uses `paramiko`. Your trick is isefull for that to. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the root logger's level to `WARN` (should be `WARNING`) in `remoteConnect.py`, and to `INFO` in `getdata.py`. I would advise that you avoid setting levels on the root logger in random modules in your application: instead, do this in all your modules where you want to use logging:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and use `logger.debug(...)`, etc. in that module. Then, in one specific place in your application (typically in your logic called from `if __name__ == '__main__':`, set the levels and handlers that you want, either programmatically via [`basicConfig`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) or a set of API calls to add handlers, formatters etc., or through the use of a declarative configuration (e.g. using `fileConfig` or `dictConfig` APIs - documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.config.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this before setting up logger2:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
```